# Problems using cv::split

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I am using OpenCV 2.4.6, and trying to generate some histograms. The original example code took an image from local storage, but I modified it to use a `VideoCapture` object. When the code gets to `cv::split()`, it brings an unhandled exception. It prompts this:

> "Unhandled exception at 0x5465B3D9 (opencv_core246.dll) in
>   visionProject.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location
>   0x1800E633."

The code I have is this:

```
            VideoCapture camera;
            camera.open(0);

            camera >> src;

            if( !src.data )
                { return -1; }

            /// Separate the image in 3 places ( B, G and R )
            vector <Mat> bgr_planes;
            split(src, bgr_planes );
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your code works well in my PC with OpenCV2.4.5.

Comment: your code now differs from your problem

Comment: I was not sure whether to edit the whole question, or create a new one. Anyways, it is now working correctly, but only if I set the project to be built as Release. Cannot use debugger yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to assistance from a friend, I was able to make it work. In order for `OpenCV` to work correctly, I have to set the build to Release in **Visual Studio**. This way, it works as it should.